# Setting a variable with keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab a credit card number on on input field with the keyup() method, but I am getting undefined when I type the variable name in the console. Yet as I type in the field the digits are being logged to the console.

```
$('#authorizenet_cc_number').keyup(function(){
        var ccNum =  $('#authorizenet_cc_number').val();
        console.log(ccNum);       
  });
```

Am I wrong in my understanding that when the value in the input changes it is stored in the ccNum variable?

Comment: Does this element exist at the time of page load? Also; instead of declaring that variable again, simply use `$(this).val();`

Comment: Because the variable is only scoped to the `keyup` function handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ccNum`'s scope is local to the keyup handler anonymous function. put it in a higher scope if you want access to it from a higher scope.

```
var ccNum; // declaration in an outer scope

$('#authorizenet_cc_number').keyup(function(){
    // no need to reselect on the input, just use "this"
    ccNum = $(this).val(); // initialization in an inner scope
    console.log(ccNum); // logs the value
});

console.log(ccNum); // also logs the value (if called after the handler has fired)
```

Comment: Following your example, I still get "ReferenceError: ccNum is not defined" when I type ccNum into the console.

Comment: First off, Thanks your patience and help. So I get the console.log, no problems there. However if I open the inspector in chrome hit escape and type in "ccNum;" it was my understanding that it would give me the value of the variable. Is this not so?

Comment: @ScottS my guess is that you're looking in jsfiddle, in which case the context of the inspector is probably not the iframe that jsfiddle runs it's code in.

Comment: So when I do this in a test file outside of magento it works fine. Obviously magento is doing something that is causing odd results. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

ccNum is local to the function, so it would be undefined unless you insert a break point in the function.

You can also add debugger, which will cause a break to happen. You can then use console to see the value of ccNum.

```
$('#authorizenet_cc_number').keyup(function(){
        var ccNum =  $('#authorizenet_cc_number').val();
        console.log(ccNum);  
        debugger;     
  });
```

Comment: If I put ccNum outside the keyup function I still get undefined. How would I make this a global variable?

Comment: Please follow jbabeys steps, if you declare it global be sure to change "var ccNum = .." to "ccNum = " as the keyword var will create a new local variable.